# How to change a large number of elements' positions without lag

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position, angular-material

I'm creating an Angular component which functions as a timeline for editing video files. (something like this):

[image: timeline]

I'm running into some issues when determining the position of all the measure bars on the timeline, though, and I'm trying to figure out a better way to position each of them. Currently, I am using conversion functions (pxToFrame and frameToPx) to convert frame values to pixel values in order to know where to position each measure bar.  When we are very zoomed in (meaning most of the timeline is off-screen, and we are scrolled to our zoomed in section), this has to be done for every pixel bar, which means the action is performed for every frame in the video file (a lot!) This causes the component to behave VERY slowly when I zoom in enough to render many measure lines. This becomes such a costly reFlow that it hangs the browser for many seconds.

I am wondering what is the best way to prevent this lag created by rendering position styles for thousands of elements?

I have tried implementing angular2-virtual-scroll, in an attempt to only render the in-view elements, instead of all of them, but the component does not have an implementation for horizontal scroll yet.

Any ideas on a better strategy to approach this with, or a way of reducing the number of reFlows when rendering this component? We are working with 10s of 1000s of measure bar elements here (for each frame in a video file), so it needs to be a pretty drastic reduction.

Thanks!

For reference,
This is my html:

```
<div
    // this.measureLineArray holds an array of numbers that represent the frames at which there should be a line
    *ngFor="let frame of this.measureLineArray"

    class="measure-line-container" 

    // This ngStyle binding is how I have been changing the position property, but it's deathly slow when we are dealing with many measure lines
    [ngStyle]="getMeasureLinePxFromFrame(frame)"
>
    // This is the class for labeled lines
    <div 
        class="measure-line-label"
        *ngIf="frame % this.labelInterval === 0"
    >
        <div class="text">{{frame.toString()}}</div>

        <div class="bar"></div>

   </div>

   // This is the class for unlabeled lines
   <div 
        class="measure-line"
        *ngIf="!(frame % this.labelInterval === 0)"
   >
        <div class="bar"></div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Here are the problematic functions that create the delay

```
// Here is the function that returns the position styling for each measure line

private getMeasureLinePxFromFrame(frame : Frame) : any
{
  let measureLineStyle = {
    'left': this.frameToPx(frame) + 'px'
  }
  return measureLineStyle;
}


// This is the conversion function, utilizing the width of the container element to determine of each measure-line

private frameToPx(frame : number) : number
{
  let currentProgress : number = frame / this.numFrames;

  return Math.floor(this.Timeline.clientWidth * currentProgress);
}
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
.measure-line-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.measure-line {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;

    .bar {
        width: 1px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: black;
    }
}

.measure-line-label {
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end; 

    .bar {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 1px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        user-select: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read these topics:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html
and 
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/02/making-your-angular-app-fast.html

Moreover, you will get lots of benefits if you spend sometime reading about change detection in Angular. There are couple suggestions how to improve that. In general, `OnPush` strategy should help. But in any case, all workarounds related to updating exact element(s) that needs to be updated. I.e. you still have to determine only list of elements that needs to be rendered/shown on page at exact time, which leads to what you call "Virtual scroll".

You can put all slides on screen, but move only 10-20 of them at the same time. When slide is out of bounds -> remove it from `activeFrames` array and pick next from `leftFrames` or `rightFrames`.

Comment: I implemented a kind of activeFrames virtual scrolling, and it really increased performance, however it is still quite laggy due to the fact that at mid zooms, I have a lot of lines to render even in-view. Is there a faster way to change the style o an element other than [NgStyle] binding? It seems to be a very expensive binding.

Comment: Did you read posts from links above? Since you have abnormal amount of updates, try to run them OUTSIDE of `NgZone` and use native browser API for that.

Comment: I was using zone.runOutsideNgZone and thought that it didn't work, but it actually helped performance a ton, I was just an idiot and was still creating measureLineArray by filtering ALL my frames, as opposed to filtering only the activeFrames. I have changed that and now it works super fast!  Thank you for the resources. I understand Angular change detection on a much better level now.